# How does a C compiler figure how to compile f(enum)?

Tags: c, enums

Say I have a C header (for some library) that defines an enum and a function that takes such an enum as argument.  I can write my own code that includes that header and links the library, but how does the compiler know what kind of int the function actually expects?  If I understand well, the standard does not require a specific method for determining what type underlies an enum, so...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "what kind of int" and "what type underlies an enum?"  Are you referring to ints being different sizes under different compilers?

Answer (score 2):

The code that calls the function and the code that implements the function presumably both share a common header with the declaration of that enumeration.  Since they're the same, the compiler generates matching code.

If you mix & match compilers, you may well end up with interoperability problems in cases like this one.

Comment: Hopefully a compiler knows what it's doing so yes, the question was more for the case of different compilers.

Comment: There are plenty of other problems when you mix & match compilers, though.  What if `int` is a different size on each, for example?